# How to extract best parameters from a CrossValidatorModel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipeline, cross-validation, apache-spark-mllib

I want to find the parameters of `ParamGridBuilder` that make the best model in CrossValidator in Spark 1.4.x,

In [Pipeline Example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-model-selection-via-cross-validation) in Spark documentation, they add different parameters (`numFeatures`, `regParam`) by using `ParamGridBuilder` in the Pipeline. Then by the following line of code they make the best model:

```
val cvModel = crossval.fit(training.toDF)
```

Now, I want to know what are the parameters (`numFeatures`, `regParam`) from `ParamGridBuilder` that produces the best model.

I already used the following commands without success:

```
cvModel.bestModel.extractParamMap().toString()
cvModel.params.toList.mkString("(", ",", ")")
cvModel.estimatorParamMaps.toString()
cvModel.explainParams()
cvModel.getEstimatorParamMaps.mkString("(", ",", ")")
cvModel.toString()
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Best parameters are [dumped to log](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a721ee52705100dbd7852f80f92cde4375517e48/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidator.scala#L104) but beats me how you can access this information from a `CrossValidatorModel` instance.

Comment: That's really frustrating. They aren't even logging it in PySpark. Such a small but important thing that's lacking... it makes me wonder if anyone is actually using this functionality.

Comment: folks, any solution for this problem in the recent versions of Spark?

Comment: you definitely can get it from `cvModel.bestModel`, please see my answer below

Comment: [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225246/how-to-access-parameters-of-the-underlying-model-in-ml-pipeline) kinda answers the question.

Answer (score 20):

One method to get a proper `ParamMap` object is to use `CrossValidatorModel.avgMetrics: Array[Double]` to find the argmax `ParamMap`:

```
implicit class BestParamMapCrossValidatorModel(cvModel: CrossValidatorModel) {
  def bestEstimatorParamMap: ParamMap = {
    cvModel.getEstimatorParamMaps
           .zip(cvModel.avgMetrics)
           .maxBy(_._2)
           ._1
  }
}
```

When run on the `CrossValidatorModel` trained in the Pipeline Example you cited gives:

```
scala> println(cvModel.bestEstimatorParamMap)
{
   hashingTF_2b0b8ccaeeec-numFeatures: 100,
   logreg_950a13184247-regParam: 0.1
}
```

Comment: Note: `maxBy` might need to be  `minBy`, depending on the value of `Evaluator.isLargerBetter`.

Answer (score 13):

```
val bestPipelineModel = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
val stages = bestPipelineModel.stages

val hashingStage = stages(1).asInstanceOf[HashingTF]
println("numFeatures = " + hashingStage.getNumFeatures)

val lrStage = stages(2).asInstanceOf[LogisticRegressionModel]
println("regParam = " + lrStage.getRegParam)
```

[source](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201505.mbox/%3CCAJTZZE6r6DnA5as-MWnN+ZTvQ=nCBa0CjJWZGaRO7LDr+1oRJA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 4):

To print everything in `paramMap`, you actually don't have to call parent:

```
cvModel.bestModel.extractParamMap()
```

To answer OP's question, to get a single best parameter, for example `regParam`:

```
cvModel.bestModel.extractParamMap().apply(cvModel.bestModel.getParam("regParam"))
```

Comment: Note that this solution works OK with a single object. It returns an empty map in the case of a Pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get the chosen parameters

```
println(cvModel.bestModel.getMaxIter)   
println(cvModel.bestModel.getRegParam)
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Answer (score 2):

this java code should work: 
`cvModel.bestModel().parent().extractParamMap()`.you can translate it to scala code
`parent()`method will return an estimator, you can get the best params then.

Comment: This is the correct answer to pySpark as well! The key is "parent"! In pySpark, I use modelOnly.bestModel.stages[-1]._java_obj.parent().getRegParam().

Answer (score 1):

This is the ParamGridBuilder()

```
paraGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(
hashingTF.numFeatures, [10, 100, 1000]
).addGrid(
    lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]
).build()
```

There are 3 stages in pipeline. It seems we can assess parameters as the following:

```
for stage in cv_model.bestModel.stages:
    print 'stages: {}'.format(stage)
    print stage.params
    print '\n'

stage: Tokenizer_46ffb9fac5968c6c152b
[Param(parent='Tokenizer_46ffb9fac5968c6c152b', name='inputCol', doc='input column name'), Param(parent='Tokenizer_46ffb9fac5968c6c152b', name='outputCol', doc='output column name')]

stage: HashingTF_40e1af3ba73764848d43
[Param(parent='HashingTF_40e1af3ba73764848d43', name='inputCol', doc='input column name'), Param(parent='HashingTF_40e1af3ba73764848d43', name='numFeatures', doc='number of features'), Param(parent='HashingTF_40e1af3ba73764848d43', name='outputCol', doc='output column name')]

stage: LogisticRegression_451b8c8dbef84ecab7a9
[]
```

However, there is no parameter in the last stage, logiscRegression.

We can also get ***weight*** and ***intercept*** parameter from logistregression like the following:

```
cv_model.bestModel.stages[1].getNumFeatures()
10
cv_model.bestModel.stages[2].intercept
1.5791827733883774
cv_model.bestModel.stages[2].weights
DenseVector([-2.5361, -0.9541, 0.4124, 4.2108, 4.4707, 4.9451, -0.3045, 5.4348, -0.1977, -1.8361])
```

Full exploration:
http://kuanliang.github.io/2016-06-07-SparkML-pipeline/

Answer (score 1):

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225246/how-to-access-parameters-of-the-underlying-model-in-ml-pipeline) kinda answers the question.

In a nutshell, you need to cast each object to its supposed-to-be class.

For the case of `CrossValidatorModel`, the following is what I did:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel

// Load CV model from S3
val inputModelPath = "s3://path/to/my/random-forest-regression-cv"
val reloadedCvModel = CrossValidatorModel.load(inputModelPath)

// To get the parameters of the best model
(
    reloadedCvModel.bestModel
        .asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
        .stages(1)
        .asInstanceOf[RandomForestRegressionModel]
        .extractParamMap()
)
```

In the example, my pipeline has two stages (a VectorIndexer and a RandomForestRegressor), so the stage index is 1 for my model.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Spark Scala 1.6.x and here is a full example of how i can set and fit a `CrossValidator` and then return the value of the parameter used to get the best model (assuming that `training.toDF` gives a dataframe ready to be used) :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

// Instantiate a LogisticRegression object
val lr = new LogisticRegression()

// Instantiate a ParamGrid with different values for the 'RegParam' parameter of the logistic regression
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)).build()

// Setting and fitting the CrossValidator on the training set, using 'MultiClassClassificationEvaluator' as evaluator
val crossVal = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(lr).setEvaluator(new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
val cvModel = crossVal.fit(training.toDF)

// Getting the value of the 'RegParam' used to get the best model
val bestModel = cvModel.bestModel                    // Getting the best model
val paramReference = bestModel.getParam("regParam")  // Getting the reference of the parameter you want (only the reference, not the value)
val paramValue = bestModel.get(paramReference)       // Getting the value of this parameter
print(paramValue)                                    // In my case : 0.001
```

You can do the same for any parameter or any other type of model.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If java，see this debug show;

```
bestModel.parent().extractParamMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Building in the solution of @macfeliga, a single liner that works for pipelines:

```
cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
    .stages.foreach(stage => println(stage.extractParamMap))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the @orangeHIX solution is perfect:

```
val cvModel = cv.fit(training)

val cvMejorModelo = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[ALSModel]

cvMejorModelo.parent.extractParamMap()

res86: org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap =
{
    als_08eb64db650d-alpha: 0.05,
    als_08eb64db650d-checkpointInterval: 10,
    als_08eb64db650d-coldStartStrategy: drop,
    als_08eb64db650d-finalStorageLevel: MEMORY_AND_DISK,
    als_08eb64db650d-implicitPrefs: false,
    als_08eb64db650d-intermediateStorageLevel: MEMORY_AND_DISK,
    als_08eb64db650d-itemCol: product,
    als_08eb64db650d-maxIter: 10,
    als_08eb64db650d-nonnegative: false,
    als_08eb64db650d-numItemBlocks: 10,
    als_08eb64db650d-numUserBlocks: 10,
    als_08eb64db650d-predictionCol: prediction,
    als_08eb64db650d-rank: 1,
    als_08eb64db650d-ratingCol: rating,
    als_08eb64db650d-regParam: 0.1,
    als_08eb64db650d-seed: 1994790107,
    als_08eb64db650d-userCol: user
}
```