# Calling JVM-based algorithms / functions from pySpark possible?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I created a set of algorithms and helpers in Scala for Spark working with different formats of measured data. They are all based on Hadoop's `FileInputFormat`. I also created some helpers to ease working with time series data from a Cassandra database. I now need some advanced functions which are already present in [Thunder](http://thunder-project.org/), plus some of my colleagues who are to work with these helper functions want to use Python. Is it somehow possible to use these helper functions from python or do I have to reimplement them?

I read through a lot of docs and only found that you can load extra jars with pyspark, but not how to use the functions.

Comment: It is actually possible.

Comment: @eliasah It depends, doesn't it? You can trigger high level transformations but it is not possible to the same thing from the worker.

Comment: That's true ! I was thinking of the other way around like what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33500704/3415409)

Comment: So, if I created the "sc.coolMeasuringDataFile" via an implicit class, can I use that from pyspark and if yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

"By accident" I found the solution: It is the "Java Gateway". This is not documented in the Spark documentation (at least I didn't find it).

Here is how it works, using a "GregorianCalendar" as an example

```
j = sc._gateway.jvm
cal = j.java.util.GregorianCalendar()
print cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

However, passing the SparkContext does not work directly. The Java SparkContext is in the `_jsc` field:

```
ref = j.java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference()
ref.set(sc)
```

this fails. However:

```
ref = j.java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference()
ref.set(sc._jsc)
```

works.

However note that `sc._jsc` returns a Java-based Spark Context, i.e., a `JavaSparkContext`. To get the original Scala `SparkContext`, you have to use:

```
sc._jsc.sc()
```

Comment: Good one ! Nevertheless it isn't documented in Spark because it's not Spark related by rather Java/Python interoperability related