# How to compute eigenvector system of a matrix using Apache PySpark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have to compute the smallest magnitude eigenvalue and it's associated eigenvector of a non symmetric matrix using PySpark libraries.

The size of [image]
 is very high and I want the computation to be distributed among the cluster's workers.

The problem is that i didn't find any API to compute eigenvalues in PySpark 2.3 [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.linalg).

I have identified two paths, but I want to avoid them:

1. to reimplement eigen value decomposition trough QR algorithm using  [`QRDecomposition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=decomposition#pyspark.mllib.linalg.QRDecomposition) available in PySpark API
2. to compute eigen value decomposition trough [scala version](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/EigenValueDecomposition.scala) class as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023860/how-to-use-a-scala-class-inside-pyspark) on Stack Overflow

Is there a simpler or better way then this last two?

I already know the existence of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428589/pyspark-and-pca-how-can-i-extract-the-eigenvectors-of-this-pca-how-can-i-calcu) post, but they are conceptually different.

Comment: Why you marked as duplicate?  I don't think it is a duplicate question. Can you explain to me how compute the smallest eigenvalue and its associated eigenvector thorugh PCA?

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding your requirements. Have you read all the answers ? It's not always just about the accepted answer. Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33500704/3415409) per example ?