# How to extract average metrics with Cross-Validation in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to perform a Cross-Validation over Random Forest in Spark 1.6.0 and I'm finding hard to obtain the evaluation metrics (precision, recall, f1...). I want the average of the metrics of all folds. Is this possible to obtain them with `CrossValidator` and `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`?

I only found examples where the evaluation is performed later over an independent test dataset and using the best model from the Cross-Validation. I'm not planning to use a train and test set, but to use all the dataframe (df) for the cross validation, let it make the splits, and then take the average metrics.

```
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().build()
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()    

crossval = CrossValidator(
    estimator=pipeline,
    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
    evaluator=evaluator,
    numFolds=5)

model = crossval.fit(df)

evaluator.evaluate(model.transform(df))
```

For now, I obtain the best model metric with the last line of the above code `evaluator.evaluate(model.transform(df))` and I'm not totally sure that I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: I highly doubt that it is possible - in Spark 1.x, even getting the best model parameters was not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749593/how-to-extract-best-parameters-from-a-crossvalidatormodel

Comment: But in this case i'm talking about the evaluation metrics, not the parameters. Is there really no way to do it? Or even with the best model ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark 2.x, it is possible to get the average metrics using `model.avgMetrics`. This returns an array of double containing the metrics used to train your cross validation model.

For `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`, this gives an array of: f1, weightedPrecision, weightedRecall, accuracy (as documented [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator)). These metrics can be overridden as needed using setter in the evaluator class.

If you also need to get the best model parameters chosen by the cross validator, please see my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749593/how-to-extract-best-parameters-from-a-crossvalidatormodel.).